# Clear HTML5 date input on iOS

Tags: ios, html, date

I have been using the input type="date" form element but have found that the "Clear" option visible on the iOS datepicker behaves like a "reset" and that there is actually no way to clear a date value.

This happens with both Chrome & Safari on iOS.

I created a codepen that illustrates this (providing you access it with an iOS device or simulator) here:

https://codepen.io/ajwgibson/pen/oPGvBB

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="the_date">The date:</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="date"
             value="2018-09-06"
             placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
             name="the_date"
             id="the_date">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a workaround for this or do I need to revert to a JavaScript datepicker rather than relying on the HTML5 date input type for iOS users?

Comment: Just discovered this after updating a bunch of jQuery Datepicker text fields to use HTML5 date fields.  Sooooo irritated at Apple right now -- this is just stupid design.  Almost tempted to resort to browser sniffing to add a manual "clear" button to the page if it's.. what?  iOS WebKit?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36977256/339440